# swift2.2 ==> swift3 ==> swift4に変換する

Tags: swift, swift3, swift4

swift2.2より

```
  let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
  let icloudURL =fileManager.URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier(nil)
  if let docURL=icloudURL?.URLByAppendingPathComponent("Documents")
```

swift4へ

```
  let fileManager = FileManager.default
  let icloudURL = fileManager.url(forUbiquityContainerIdentifier: nil)
  if let docURL =　icloudURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("Documents")
```

と変換しているのですが、
Value of type 'URL?' has no member 'URLByAppendingPathComponent'というエラーが表示されます。

質問ばかりで申し訳ないです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`icloudURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("Documents")`
ではなく
`icloudURL?.appendingPathComponent("Documents")`
だと思います。

Comment: Value of optional type 'URL?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'? というエラーが表示されます。　icloudURL!. と記述してもダメなようです。

Comment: それは単純に例外が起こってクラッシュしているだけではありませんか？

Comment: `icloudURL?.`だといかがでしょう？

Comment: if let docURL=icloudURL?.URLByAppendingPathComponent("Documents") { 　　とすると　　Value of type 'URL' has no member 'URLByAppendingPathComponent'　というエラーになります。

Comment: @tamatw2020 もちろんです。私が回答で書き換えているメソッドを使って下さい

Comment: 失礼しました。エラーが解除されました。

Comment: @tamatw2020 よかったです。私もはじめミスの回答をしてしまい申し訳ないです。

Comment: @tamatw2020 さん、解決できたようで何よりです。ただ前スレでもそうなのですが、ご質問のタイトルがとてもわかりやすいとは言えません。Swift2→4の変換で引っかかりそうなところは山ほどあるので、エラーメッセージの内容や、引っかかっているところで使っているメソッドなど、重要な情報をご質問タイトル中に含めていただくことで、同じ問題に悩んでいる多数の開発者がそのスレッドを見つけやすくなります。あれこれ問題続きで大変なのだとは思いますが、できればお時間をとってそこらへんにもご配慮いただけると、あなたがご質問を書かれたことがより多くの人の役に立ちますので、ご一考ください。

Comment: 返事が遅くなり申し訳ございません。今後,質問の仕方など注意するようにいたします。ありがとうございました。